# How to write Sse events in Ktor

Tags: javascript, kotlin, server-sent-events, ktor

I'm getting a post request to download something, I need to send download process to client, currently I'm trying to use Server Sent Events for this and `EventSource`, but it is not working.

My client JS

```
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const es = new EventSource("/download/process");
es.onmessage = function (event) {
const data = event.data;
console.log("Displaying:" + data);

if (result.innerText.length === 0) {
    result.innerText = data;
} else {
    result.innerText = result.innerText + "\n" + data;
}
    result.scrollTop = result.scrollHeight;
}
```

Server

```
val flo = MutableSharedFlow<String>()

routing {
    route("download") {
        get("process") {
            call.response.cacheControl(CacheControl.NoCache(null))
            call.respondBytesWriter(ContentType.Text.EventStream) {
                flo.collect {
                    writeStringUtf8(it)
                    flush()
                }
            }
        }
        post("start") {
            // Get parameters here
            runBlocking {
                // Perform download and send to client event throughout
                flo.tryEmit(it)
            }
            call.respondText("Download finished")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ktor supports SSE since version 3.0.0 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-6172) which isn't released yet. In the meantime, you can check this feature out by using the EAP version (`3.0.0-eap-800`) and the `https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap` repository.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is there a planned release date for version 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@aleksei-tirman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13963150/aleksei-tirman) answer solved it. I added `maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap")` to repositories in my Gradle build file, and started using ktor version `3.0.0-eap-800`. The SSE plugin is `io.ktor:ktor-server-sse-jvm:3.0.0-eap-800`.